# Wanted: Matlab example of an anonymous function returning more than 1 output

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, anonymous-function

I use anonymous functions for simple data value transforms. The anonymous functions are defined with the following syntax

```
sqr = @(x) x.^2;
```

I would like to have a simple anonymous function that returns more than one output that can be used as follows . . .

```
[b,a] = myAnonymousFunc(x);
```

The Matlab documentation suggests that this is possible, but it does not give an example of the syntax needed to define such a function.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html#f4-71162

What is the syntax to define such a function [**in a single line, like the code example at the top of my post**]?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
>> f = @(x)deal(x.^2,x.^3);
>> [a,b]=f(3)
a =
     9
b =
    27
```

With this example, you need to ensure that you only call `f` with exactly two output arguments, otherwise it will error.

**EDIT**

At least with recent versions of MATLAB, you can return only some of the output arguments using the `~` syntax:

```
>> [a,~]=f(3)
a =
     9
>> [~,b]=f(3)
b =
    27
```

Comment: Perfect. I can now define and use a one-pole-filter functions as easily as this `>> opf = @(dt,tc)deal(dt/tc,[1 dt/tc-1]);
>> [b,a] = opf(1/44100, 0.0050)`

Answer (score 8):

If you'd rather not skip outputs using tilde ~ nor output a cell array, you'd only need an auxiliary anonymous function:

```
 deal2 = @(varargin) deal(varargin{1:nargout});
 myAnonymousFunc = @(x) deal2(x.^2, x.^3);
```

then you can obtain just the first output argument or both first and second one:

```
x = 2;
[b,a] = myAnonymousFunc(x)
b = myAnonymousFunc(x)
```

results:

> b =
>        4
>
> a =
>        8
>
> b =
>        4

Answer (score 7):

You can get multiple outputs from an anonymous function if the function being called returns more than a single output. See this [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/31/multiple-outputs/) on the MathWorks website for examples of this in action.

There are two ways to get multiple outputs from an anonymous function:

- Call a function which returns multiple outputs

  From the blog post linked to, they use the [`eig`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/eig.html) function like so

  ```
  fdoubleEig = @(x) eig(2*x)
  [e, v] = fdoubleEig(magic(3))
  ```
- Alternatively you can construct an anonymous function which returns multiple outputs using the [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html) function.

  Here is one I made up:

  ```
  >>> f = @(x, y, z) deal(2*x, 3*y, 4*z)
  >>> [a, b, c] = f(1, 2, 3)

  a = 
       2
  b = 
       6
  c = 
       12
  ```

**Edit**: As noted by Sam Roberts, and in the blog post I link to, you must use the correct number of output arguments when using `deal`, otherwise an error is thrown. One way around this is to return a cell of results. For example

```
>>> f = @(x, y, z) {2*x, 3*y, 4*z}

>>> t = f(1, 2, 3)

>>> [a, b, c] = t{:}

    a = 
         2
    b = 
         6
    c = 
         12
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't even think about the deal function.

Comment: @Chris I added a better way around the issue of returning other numbers of output arguments to my answer.

Comment: @SamRoberts That looks good, although you will need multiple `~`s for functions which return more than 2 values. This is (one of the places) where I much prefer Python, tuple unpacking lets you write `a, _ = func(...)` where an arbitrary number of arguments can be bound to `_`. AFAIK MATLAB does not have an equivalent.

Comment: @Chris That's true, you can't do that in MATLAB. If you were writing a regular function, you could use `varargout` to get a similar effect to the Python method, but you can't easily do that with anonymous functions.