# Optimizing code through vectorization

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I wanted to speed up some nested for-loops over a multidimensional function, so I made my attempt to vectorize it. Here I've made a simplified version of the type of code I'm running:

```
xval = [1, 2, 3, 4];
thetaval = [0, 0, 0, 0];

p11 =  @(x, theta) 1*x;
p12 =  @(x, theta) 2*x.*exp(1i*theta);
p21 =  @(x, theta) 2*x.*exp(1i*theta);
p22 =  @(x, theta) 4*x.^2;

a = bsxfun(p11, xval, thetaval)
b = bsxfun(p12, xval, thetaval)
c = bsxfun(p21, xval, thetaval)
d = bsxfun(p22, xval, thetaval)

combo = [a, b, c, d]

q = size(xval);
length = q(2);

reshape(combo, 2, 2,4)
```

My main question is:
Is this code "properly vectorized"? That is, am I using matlab's resources efficiently? Can I get it to be even faster?  How about when xval and thetaval are about 50,000 elements each?

Some less important side-questions:

Is there a more elegant way to write this code? I feel like I'm doing a very simple task and would be surprised if there was not more streamlined infrastructure for handling a vector of functions. I see [simple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634491/wanted-matlab-example-of-an-anonymous-function-returning-more-than-1-output) of implementing this, but bsxfun breaks when I give it a function that's really an array of functions.

Calling each of these functions individually is certainly inelegant, but is it also inefficient?  The amount of functions in my real code right now are 36, but later I might want to upgrade to 100 or even 1000.

Comment: Why would you need a `bsxfun` if your `xval` and `thetaval` are the same `size`? Just do `a = xval; b = 2*xval.*exp(1i*thetaval); c = b; d = 4*xval.^2;`...

Comment: for some reason I thought bsxfun is faster and that I should be looking for places to put it in my code. But when you write it out like that, it makes it really seem like what I'm doing is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @StevenSagona bsxfun is faster that a lot of things, but you dont need it for standard operations. MATLAB would be a silly programming language if `bsxfun(@times,A,B)` would be faster than `A.*B`