# How to write a different handle objective function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function

I have a function with multiple outputs, let's assume them as different objective function `f1` and function `f2`. How could I write the two handling functions for the two objectives?

```
function [f1,f2] = myfunc(x)
f1=x^2;
f2=sqrt(x);
end
```

I gave a try

```
[obj1,obj2] = @(x)myfunc(x)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wanted: Matlab example of an anonymous function returning more than 1 output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634491/wanted-matlab-example-of-an-anonymous-function-returning-more-than-1-output)

Comment: Why not write two separate functions?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Most likely because he often needs both functions to be evaluated for the same argument.

Comment: @Max that argument might hold ground if the two functions share a lot of computation. Otherwise you can always write a trivial function that evaluates the two separate functions with the same argument: `@(x) [f1(x), f2(x)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Make f1 and f2 function handles in `myfunc()` as follows:

```
function [f1, f2] = myfunc()
f1 = @(x) x^2;
f2 = @(x) sqrt(x);
end
```

Then you can call them from your main script/command window as:

```
[obj1,obj2] = myfunc();
x = 2; % just to test the output
obj1(x);
obj2(x);
```

Comment: Thanks sir,but my objective is to return the values of f1 and to optimize only f2,function [f1,f2]=multfunc(x1,x2)
f1=x1*log(x2);
f2=x2^2;
end  [~,f2]=@(x1,x2)multfunc(x1,x2)
then in the error is:Only functions can return multiple values

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/555613-how-to-handle-functions-with-multiple-outputs?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view#answer_457759